# Asynchronous php loop

Tags: php, json, parsing, asynchronous, metadata

I'm building a site where I have a json array of URL's, I use these urls to parse the meta data to display on the site. I want to show a thumbnail image, title and description. The issue that I've found is that it takes almost 10 seconds to get the data ready to be displayed in the site.

My question I want to ask is this: How should I go about to make it asynchronous, so that the loading time is drastically reduced. Does anyone have suggestions for this?

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsonData, true);

<div class="container" id="content">
    <?php
        $jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
        $json = json_decode($jsonData, true);

        function file_get_contents_curl($url){

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }


        foreach ($json['posts'] as $post){

            $html = file_get_contents_curl($post['url']);

            //parsing begins here:
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$doc->loadHTML($html);
            $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

            //get and display what you need:
            $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

            for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
            {
                $meta = $metas->item($i);
                if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 
                    $image = $meta->getAttribute('content');}
                if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
                    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            }

            $output = "<a href='$post[url]'><br>";
            $output .= "<div class='thumbnail'><br>";
            $output .= "<img src='$image'><br>";
            $output .= "<p class='article-headline'>$title</p><br>";
            $output .= "<p class='article-excerpt'>$description</p><br>";
            $output .= "</div></a>";

            echo $output; 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

my data.json file looks like this but with about 16 urls. The idea is that it's supposed to be able to handle an array with alot more URL's:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "url":"https://medium.com/s/story/the-absurdity-of-student-loan-debt-fb61fdca7d8c"
        },
        {
            "url":"https://medium.com/s/in-defense-of-the-worst-human-emotions/jealousy-is-a-brat-eed054493965"
        },
        {
            "url":"https://medium.com/swlh/chatbots-were-the-next-big-thing-what-happened-5fc49dd6fa61"
        },
        {
            "url":"https://medium.com/s/trustissues/my-so-called-millennial-entitlement-9be84343c713"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is asynchronous a requirement? What about simply caching the curl result?

Comment: Are you doing this on every page load? Why not save the result to a database and query that instead? The data on those remote pages probably wont change often so you could have a scheduled task that updates the database one a week or similar

Comment: No there is no requirement, I just thought it might be a good solution. Caching might be better, I will try that out! Thank you.